# Jquery Cycle issue or css issue in Chrome/Safari for Mac

Tags: jquery, css, safari, google-chrome, jquery-cycle

Hi i have used the jquery cycle plugin to create multiple simple sliding galleries. In Chrome/Safair on Mac the browser is not loading the images.

Here is the [link](http://designbychief.com/mis-chief.aspx)

the js i am using is here, although it could be a css issue..?  I am struggling to find the real problem.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('.slides').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this), $ss = $this.closest('.slideshow');
            var prev = $ss.find('a.prev'), next = $ss.find('a.next');
            $this.cycle({
                prev: prev,
                next: next,
                fx: 'scrollLeft', 
                speed:  'fast', 
                timeout: 0 
            });
    });

    });
```

CSS

```
.slideshow {
width:476px;
height:287px;
float:left;
margin-right:30px;
position:relative;
z-index:0;
margin-bottom:20px;
}

.slides {
position:absolute;
top:0;
left:0;
z-index:1;
}

a.prev {
display:block;
width:23px;
height:22px;
background:red;
position:absolute;
z-index:1000;
background: url(../images/next_prev.png) no-repeat 0 0;
top:133px;
left:-11px;
}

a.next {
display:block;
width:23px;
height:22px;
background:red;
position:absolute;
z-index:1000;
background: url(../images/next_prev.png) no-repeat -23px 0;
top:133px;
right:-11px;
}
```

Markup:

```
<div class="slideshow"> 
                <div class="slides"> 
                    <img src="images/chief_st_1.jpg" alt="CHIEF stationery + literature" /> 
                    <img src="images/chief_st_3.jpg" alt="CHIEF stationery + literature" /> 
                    <img src="images/chief_st_2.jpg" alt="CHIEF stationery + literature" /> 
                </div> 
                <a class="prev" href="#"></a> <a class="next" href="#"></a> 
            </div>
```

Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Have added css and html above.

Answer (score 2):

This issue has been reported by a very large number of people here:

http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=113556

Unfortunately no resolution yet, however it has been re-created and I have done so as well.

Just some info

Answer (score 1):

Haven't got a Mac but Firebug displays:

```
[cycle] terminating; too few slides: 1
[cycle] terminating; too few slides: 1
[cycle] terminating; too few slides: 1
```

Does this help?

Comment: I cans ee this in Firebug but its not clear what it actually means! :-/

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be working for me. Checked in chrome on a Mac and FF...still ahving issues?